# Calculation of firebase array elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pulling down an array from firebase that looks like this:­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

```
{­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
  item1:{
         startTime = 1487481288971,
         endTime = 1487499053775
         },
  item2:{
         startTime = 1487467133696,
         endTime = 1487481231141
         }
}
```

And for each element, I want to know the duration (endTime-startTime).
I'm trying to save the duration back into the same json that the start and end times are in

```
  cycles.on("child_added",function(snapshot){
      snapshot.val()["duration"] = snapshot.val().endTime - snapshot.val().startTime
  })
```

So that it can be referenced the same way in the HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in cycles">
  <td>{{c.startTime}} </td>
  <td>{{c.endTime}} </td>
  <td>{{c.duration}} </td>
</tr>
```

It however comes back undefined.

Should this work? and if not what's the best approach here?

I've also tried saving them into a separate array, which works, but there's extra complexities when the list is being reverse sorted, and new elements are being added.

Many thanks!

Comment: can you post more code???

Comment: The code you shared doesn't do anything to make the data available to the HTML. Without seeing how you do that, it'll be hard to help.